# TortoiseSVN only works on checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can do the initial checkout just fine but I can't commit or update any repos.  I'm running through a VPN.  The issue is only with by desktop Windows 10 system.  The work laptop (win10), on the same network sitting right beside the desktop, works fine.  I can view the repo in a browser (Firefox and Edge) just fine, but only have I accept the self signed certificate.  The error I get is:

> Unable to connect to a repository at URL
>   'https://XXXX/svn/XXX'
>   Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using different credentials between the desktop and the laptop?

Comment: yes, different.  didn't think of that

Comment: So you could check if both credentials have write access to the repository

Comment: just checked, the laptop that is working has different credentials than what is needed to log into the SVN repo, so I don't think that's it